# Remove public when using $_GET with htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I' am learning to create a my own PHP MVC Framework. Here is my URL Structure: `http://www.mvc.dev/public/controller/methold/params`

I' am using the following function to get the current URL. The following function returns `public/test1/test2/test3`. I don't want the `public` to show.

```
function parseUrl(){
  if( isset($_GET['url']) ){
    echo $_GET['url'];
  }
}
```

**.htaccess**
Makes the URI into a Query String

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help, how can I remove `public` from `public/test1/test2/test3`.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're just doing it for testing purposes, but in your production environment you should never `echo` any user-supplied information directly to the browser (like `echo $_GET['url'];`) without properly escaping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this .htaccess in your `DocumentRoot` (a level above `public`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Then you can use links as `http://www.mvc.dev/controller/methold/params`